# Should I pass data between directive and service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I have a page with a **controller** that has a **directive** that displays a form with inputs.

The **directive** has an object that contains all the inputs (and their ng-model) that are displayed on the form. This binds the form inputs data to the object variable inside the directive.

I need to display results (and other actions) submiting the data of the form.

For that I created a **service** that handles the business logic  and thae ajax calls.

The questions here is... **how should I access the form data from the service to perform the required actions?** I thought about accessing the directive variable from the service, but I'm not sure how to do it and if this is the right way in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `service` should hold a model which is basically the javascript object of your form.

The `directive` should inject the service and add that object on his scope(a reference).

The `directive's template` should speak with the `directive's scope` and display the form.

Changing a value on the view will reflect the service since we they have the same reference and the view will update the directives scope since there is two way binding.

Comment: Then, as I understand, I'll have to move the object model to the service and then the directive will use the variable from the service. Is there any best practice to this injection?

Comment: A service should keep the state and do all the $http calls. The controllers and directives should inject the service and access the state. The controller should do the databinding and act as the html's best friend.

Answer (score 0):

admittedly I'm still working things out, but I think if you add in a controller between your directive and service things will be bit clearer. This is the most compact example of the basic structure I've been playing with.. (forgive the coffeescript if that's not your thing).

```
angular.module 'app'

.controller 'KeyFormCtrl', (SessionService, $scope, $location, $log) ->
  @error = null
  @message = null
  @keySent = false
  @creds =
    username: null

  @sendKey = ->
    SessionService.sendKey({ username: @creds.username })
    .then(
      (resp) =>
        @keySent = true
      (err) =>
        @error   = err.error
    )

.directive 'eaKeyForm', ->
  {
    restrict: 'AE'
    scope: {}
    templateUrl: 'session/key-form.html'
    replace: true
    controller: 'KeyFormCtrl'
    controllerAs: 'kfc'
    bindToController: true
  }
```

session/key-form.html:

```
<form>
    <div ng-show="kfc.error">{{kfc.error}}</div>
    <div ng-show="kfc.message">{{kfc.message}}</div>
    <div ng-show="kfc.keySent">
        An account key has been sent to {{kfc.creds.username}}.<br />
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="kfc.keySent">
        <input type="email" ng-model="kfc.creds.username">
        <button ng-click="kfc.sendKey()">Send Key</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
     .directive('myAweseomDirective', ['MyAwesomeService', function(MyAwesomeService) {
         return {
             link: function(scope) {

                 scope.saveFormDetails = function() {
                     MyAweseomeService.saveInformation(scope.data);
                     //where data is the ng-model for the form
                 }
             }
         };
}])
.service('MyAweseomService', function() {
    MyAwesomeService.saveInformation = function(data) {
        //do whatever you want to with the data 
    }
});
```